# Selenium issue while handling table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the issue that when I put this code in my project. I am facing the issue that the code is not working in my system. I am watching the video in which the code is working fine but in my system it gives me the error... (terminated) Tableexercise[Java Application]C:........... Kindly help me to resolve this issue I will be very grateful to you. Here is the code below

```
package TablesTesting;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Tableexercise

{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "H:\\Chrome Web Driver\\Chrome92\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/36286/wi-vs-pak-1st-t20i-pakistan-tour-of-west-indies-2021");
        
        WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']"));

        int rowcount =  table.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).size();
        
        int count = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold'] div:nth-child(3)")).size();
    
        for(int i=1; i<count; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(table.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold'] div:nth-child(3)")).get(i));
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Can we have full error stacktrace  ?

Comment: Please mention the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is that `div[class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold'] div:nth-child(3)` is not a correct locator. No element on that page matching this locator.
Also in order to select elements inside element it is preferably to use XPath as shown below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "H:\\Chrome Web Driver\\Chrome92\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/36286/wi-vs-pak-1st-t20i-pakistan-tour-of-west-indies-2021");
        
WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr')]"));

int rowcount =  table.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'cb-col-8') and(contains(@class,'text-bold'))]")).size();
```

It's unclear to me what are you trying to get by `div[class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold'] div:nth-child(3)`, so I can give a working locator for it.